# Can i use expo-linking for a phone call

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm developing a mobile application using React Native Expo and I would like to be able to make a phone call with expo-linking and the list of my contacts with expo-contact if possible. Thanks

edit: i managed to do what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps :)

```
import * as Linking from "expo-linking";

Linking.openURL('phone:+1786256252'); // phone
Linking.openURL('sms:+1786256252'); // sms
Linking.openURL('https://wa.me/+1786256252'); // whatsapp
Linking.openURL('https://t.me:+1786256252'); // telegram
```